# Why doesn't my check of an element work on other pages?

Tags: javascript

I have written some code to disable scrolling in modal for one particular page of the site, however when I started browsing different pages on the site all of them became affected by the code I wrote and disrupt them from functioning properly. I got an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

As I understand it the program tries to excute the code for an element that doesn't exist on that page. Therefore I have decided to write a condition that will only execute the code if the required element exist on the page.
Here is what I made:

```
let popUp = document.getElementsByClassName(".js-popUp");
if (typeof popUp != "undefined" && popUp != null) {
  document
    .querySelector(".js-element__buildOpenPopUp")
    .addEventListener("click", function () {
      const itemList = document.querySelector(".js-popUp");
      const testItem = document.querySelectorAll(".js-popUp__itemList");

      if (itemList.classList.contains("hidden-block")) {
        addScrollableTarget(testItem);
        disablePageScroll();
      }
    });
}
```

As far as my knowledge of JS go the part with

```
let popUp = document.getElementsByClassName(".js-popUp");
    if (typeof popUp != "undefined" && popUp != null) {
```

should check if the is a certain element on the page but for some reason I still get errors on the other pages.
What did I do wrong with this?

I am sorry in advance if the example is not particulary clear. I only started to practice JavaScript very recently and the obvious things may not be so obviuos to me.

Comment: You have to check if `.js-element__buildOpenPopUp` exists. Currently `document.querySelector(".js-element__buildOpenPopUp")` doesn't find anything and returns `undefined`. `.addEventListener("click", function () {` on `undefined` causes the given error message.

Comment: Try putting your code into the `window.onload` function

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName(".dfsascxsc34dv-245dvxzf")` returns an empty `HTMLCollection`, which is neither undefined nor null. Among other issues, that check is not doing anything.